# How to handle strings with spaces in the middle in ANTLR

Tags: antlr

I want to parse following lines of a file and identify the Student name and the age separately.

```
Student Tim Jonh (25)
Student Mack Woo (30)
```

The age is a number and the name may or may not have spaces at the middle. I created following ANTLR grammar for the above.

However this parses the name as multiple words. But I want to take it as is "Tim Jonh" or "Mack Woo" with the spaces at the middle. That is if there are 2 spaces at the middle it should read it as is.

```
grammar school;

students        : (student)*                        ;
student         : 'Student' studentname '(' age ')' ;
studentname     : (NAME)+                           ;
age             : INT                               ;
NAME            : [a-zA-Z]+                         ;
INT             : [0-9]+                            ;

WS              : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip                ;
```

Please advice how I should change my grammar.

Please consider that this was prepared for the question and reading the name as multiple words to the application will not work for the actual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grammar school;

students        : (student)*                        ;
student         : 'Student' studentname '(' age ')' ;
studentname     : NAME                              ;
age             : INT                               ;
NAME            : WORD (WS WORD)*                   ;
fragment WORD   : [a-zA-Z]+                         ;
INT             : [0-9]+                            ;

WS              : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip                ;
```

Comment: I would use `studentname: : WORD+ ;` instead. It's simpler and works also for any number of whitespaces. The given solution will fail as soon as you add a second space char between any 2 name parts.

Comment: @MikeLischke That would produce two tokens per student name. Or would it be any different from what OP originally posted? Also, second space won't break it since `WS` is defined as `1..n` repetitions.

Comment: You are right and it depends on the usage scenario of the OP whether  everything has to stay in one token. It's just very unusual since spaces are in almost all languages separators.

Comment: @MikeLischke I agree it's unusual, but I read the last sentence of the question this way.